# ClickOnce - change some files BeforePublish

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce

I have an C# application which i want to publish with ClickOnce.

The whole progress already works fine, but now i need to change some files in the

> app.publish\Application Files\appname_1_5_9_58

folder before the whole app gets uploaded.

So i want handle this in the .csproj file

For example i already do something like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish" >
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)\obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)" />
</Target>
```

My question: is there a variable for the folder (appname_1_5_9_58) like the $(ProjectDir) or $(TargetFileName)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been a while for me.  $(PublishDir) is the staging area where MSBuild copies the published files to.  The default value of PublishDir is "bin\$(Configuration)\app.publish\". Try that?

Comment: Thank you, `$(PublishDir)\Application Files\**\*.deploy` dit the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(PublishDir)` is the staging area where MSBuild copies the published files to. The default value of PublishDir is `bin\$(Configuration)\app.publish\`.